# Scala RxJava argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type

Tags: scala, rx-java2, vert.x

I was trying to implement simple websocket handling using Vertx toolchain using RxJava library and Scala language.

And I'm getting error passing anonymous class to RxJava `map` method

```
websocket
    .flatMap(socket => socket.toObservable)
    .map(new Function[Buffer, String] {
      override def apply(msg: Buffer): String = {
        msg.toString
      }
    })
```

Compiler stack trace:

```
Error:(61, 6) no type parameters for method map: (x$1: io.reactivex.functions.Function[_ >: io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer, _ <: R])io.reactivex.Observable[R] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (io.reactivex.functions.Function[io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer,String])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : io.reactivex.functions.Function[io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer,String]
 required: io.reactivex.functions.Function[_ >: io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer, _ <: ?R]
Note: io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer <: Any, but Java-defined trait Function is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
    .map(new Function[Buffer, String] {


Error:(61, 10) type mismatch;
 found   : io.reactivex.functions.Function[io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer,String]
 required: io.reactivex.functions.Function[_ >: io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer, _ <: R]
    .map(new Function[Buffer, String] {
```

map method signature in RxJava:

```
@CheckReturnValue
    @SchedulerSupport(SchedulerSupport.NONE)
    public final <R> Observable<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(mapper, "mapper is null");
        return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableMap<T, R>(this, mapper));
    }
```

In compiler stack trace I see that function receives lower bound `Buffer` and it should work but it doesn't.

How to fix compile time issue passing right lambda to `map` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify type parameter:

```
websocket
  .flatMap(socket => socket.toObservable)
  .map[String]((msg: Buffer) => {
    msg.toString
  })
```

or

```
websocket
  .flatMap(socket => socket.toObservable)
  .map[String](new Function[Buffer, String] {
    override def apply(msg: Buffer): String = {
      msg.toString
    }
  })
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. I'm just curious, why can't scala determine the types automatically like java does in similar case ?

Comment: For example, that code compiles but it looks ugly: val wsMsgs: Observable[Json] = websocket.flatMap(socket => socket.toObservable)
    .map[String](_.toString)
    .map[Either[ParsingFailure, Json]](parse(_))
    .flatMap(new Function[Either[ParsingFailure, Json], Observable[Json]] {
    override def apply(json: Either[ParsingFailure, Json]): Observable[Json] = {
      json match {
        case Left(failure) =>
          logger.error(s"Can't parse received json: $failure")
          Observable.empty()
        case Right(jsonObject) => Observable.just(jsonObject)
      }
    }
  })

Comment: In Javascript or Python (or any other dynamically typed language) you wouldn't have issues with type inference ;) Scala is a language with more advanced type system than in Java. For example there is `Nothing` in Scala and no such thing (i.e. universal subtype) in Java. So it's possible that Java compiler can infer type `String` while for Scala compiler both types `String` and `Nothing` are legitimate options. Using language with more advanced features is not for free. Algorithms compiler uses become trickier and this means that a programmer should be ready to help compiler sometimes.

Comment: For example Idris has even more advanced type system than Scala (in some sense) so you should annotate types there even more often. 
Especially you should be ready for some inconveniences in case of Java-Scala interop. It's your choice to use RxJava in Scala rather than RxScala, fs2, akka-streams etc.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation. I put code example to code share: https://codeshare.io/508DBv . It's strange for me that for some function I need to specify type (e.g. map) and for another (flatMap) - don't (but need to specify types directly in the code).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181569/discussion-between-daryl-and-dmytro-mitin).